# When do you need to .Include related entities in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

This seems arbitrary to me when I have to actually `.Include()` related entities and when I don't. In some cases, EF gives me the info for the related entities without it and in other cases, it can't do anything with the related entities because I didn't include them:

#### Works without .Include();

This is an example where I'm loading data without .Include();

```
public class InvoiceService
{
    private ApplicationDbContext db { get; set; }
    public InvoiceService(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        db = context;
    }

    public Invoice Get(int id)
    {
        return db.Invoices.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
    }
}

public partial class ShowInvoice : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private InvoiceService invoiceService;

    private readonly ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext();
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        invoiceService = new InvoiceService(context);
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            int.TryParse(Request.QueryString["invoiceId"].ToString(), out int invoiceId);
            LoadInvoice(invoiceId);
        }
    }

    private void LoadInvoice(int invoiceId)
    {
        var invoice = invoiceService.Get(invoiceId);
        // Other code irrelevant to the question goes here.
    }
}
```

Here follows the result which includes the data for the Company associated with the invoice I'm requested:
[image]

As you can see, the information for the company definitely comes through but was not explicitly included.

#### Doesn't work without .Include();

Conversely, I've done some mapping to do with invoices in this same project and I got NullReferenceExceptions when fetching the related entities property values because I didn't `.Include()`.

This method gets all the approved timesheet entries for the specified company. This viewmodel is exclusively to be used when manipulating the association of timesheet entries for an invoice (so you're invoicing based on the timesheet entries selected).

```
public List<InvoiceTimesheetViewModel> GetInvoiceTimesheetsByCompanyId(int companyId)
{
    var factory = new TimesheetViewModelsFactory();

    var timesheets = db.Timesheets.Where(x => x.Approved && x.Company.Id == companyId && !x.Deleted).ToList();
    return factory.GetInvoiceTimesheetsViewModel(timesheets);
}
```

NullReferenceExceptions occurred in the factory that maps the timesheet entities to the viewmodel:

```
public List<InvoiceTimesheetViewModel> GetInvoiceTimesheetsViewModel(List<Timesheet> timesheets)
{
    var model = new List<InvoiceTimesheetViewModel>();
    foreach (var timesheet in timesheets)
    {
        var start = DateTime.Parse((timesheet.DateAdded + timesheet.StartTime).ToString());
        var finished = DateTime.Parse((timesheet.DateCompleted + timesheet.EndTime).ToString());
        DateTime.TryParse(timesheet.RelevantDate.ToString(), out DateTime relevant);

        model.Add(new InvoiceTimesheetViewModel
        {
            RelevantDate = relevant,
            BillableHours = timesheet.BillableHours,
            Finished = finished,
            Id = timesheet.Id,
            StaffMember = timesheet.StaffMember.UserName, // NRE here.
            Start = start,
            Task = timesheet.Task.Name // NRE here.
        });
    }
    return model;
}
```

To fix these, I had to change the query that fetches the data to the following:

```
var timesheets = db.Timesheets.Include(i => i.StaffMember).Include(i => i.Task)
            .Where(x => x.Approved && x.Company.Id == companyId && !x.Deleted).ToList();
```

Why is Entity Framework sometimes happy to give me data without me explicitly requesting that data and sometimes it requires me to explicitly request the data or else throws an error?

And how am I to know when I need to explicitly include the data I'm looking for and when I don't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entity framework uses lazy loading to load child relationships. **For lazy loading to work property in the model should be marked with `virtual` keyword.** Ef overrides it and adds lazy loading support.

When you have no virtual property EF has no way to load your child relationship data later, so the only time it's possible to do - during initial data loading using `Include`.

```
public class Timesheet
{
    ...
    public virtual StaffMember StaffMember { get; set; }
    public virtual Task Task { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Awesome thanks for explaining. So would you say best practice would be to always make your related entities `virtual` when you're building your models? Or would it be better to explicitly `.Include()` them in your queries?

Comment: Lazy loading is generally causing a lot of performance issues. Each time lazy loading is happening a query is hitting your database. In your example you are doing a foreach and accessing a lazy loaded property: it will cause Select N+1 issue. In that case Include would be better. OTOH using lazy loading causes us to write less code and could be used where you are not using it in cycles or performance isn't critical.

Comment: On my latest projects we decided to disable lazy loading for performance reasons. On projects where Lazy loading is enabled the best would be to mark virtual navigation properties and collections(has almost unnoticeable performance impact due to virtual table method lookup), but use it where appropriate (avoid Select N+1 problem).

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your models. If you have marked relational properties as `virtual` then you'll need to use `.Include` so EF knows that you need it. It is Lazy Loading. Preserves machine's memory and DB requests.

Comment: Not to be cheeky but are you sure? My entities (StaffMember and Task) on the timesheet are not marked virtual and I had to `.Include` them. Looks like its the other way around?

Comment: Which properties are not loading without include? Are all of them collections?